# Hiding button in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide one or more radio buttons in bootstrap. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9664/).

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("input[value='other']").parent().hide();
}, 1000);
```

It works as expected except that removing either of the side buttons leaves the new side button incorrectly styled (no rounded corners). In the example removing 'female' works fine, but removing 'male' or 'other' results in an incorrectly styled button row.

What would be the easiest way to fix this? Note that I might have to unhide the buttons under circumstances so just removing it from the DOM is not desirable.

Comment: will you considering of adding the border-radius manually? (since it is just 3 options)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap applies style to the last element.

**Solution I** *(If you don't want to remove the button and just hide it):*

Create a class in css to give rounded corners and add the class to `prev()` element. and When you `show()` the element just remove this class. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0op3bydm/1/)

JS:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("input[value='other']").parent().prev().addClass('pseudoLast')
    $("input[value='other']").parent().hide();

}, 1000);
```

CSS:

```
.pseudoLast{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
}
```

when you `show` the button just do:

```
$("input[value='other']").parent().prev().removeClass('pseudoLast')
$("input[value='other']").parent().show();
```

**Solution II** :

You need to remove the element [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9667/)

js:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("input[value='other']").parent().remove(); // < here
}, 1000);
```

Later you can append the element.

Comment: I thought he mentioned "removing it from the DOM is not desirable."

Comment: @EricT: For the same reason there is solution II. :) .

Comment: @EricT: I have changed the order and i think solution one is the thing user is looking for ryt?

Comment: yup, probably I think. Just wait for the thread starter came back to verify.

Answer (score 3):

The CSS applies the style to the last element in the 'btn-group' the hide() method just adds 'display:none' to the element and the CSS still interprets it as the last element because it is still part of the DOM.

So you will need to remove it completely from the DOM

```
otherEl = $("input[value='other']").parent();
$("input[value='other']").parent().remove();
```

Add it later like so:

```
$("#gender").append(otherEl);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/j1am57r7/

I can't see any benefits for a Non-DOM removal approach to the one above but let me know if you do

Comment: I thought he mentioned "removing it from the DOM is not desirable."

Comment: Any alternative to removing it from the DOM is just going to involve CSS additions and more JS

Comment: Adding and removing buttons can get fiddly if we are also moving the element around between different toolbars. Because then you have to track where it should go when made visible etc. Still probably cleaner than trying to work around it with CSS hacks though.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the class "d-none" to make the button as diplay none